# NSString mede up of a single word is passed as NSNull when the UILabel is in has minimum font scale or minimum font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, sizetofit

When I'm trying to pass the value of a NSString made up of a single word from a cell with the minimum font scale or size set, it seem to work checking with NSLogs, but when I'm trying to compare it with another string it gives me a [NSNull length] unrecognised selector sent etc. With string composed by more words it works fine. I think it's a bug of Xcode 7. Has anyone else experience that? Is there a work around?

I tried setting the label on the cell both programmatically and on Interfece Builder, with the same result. My custom tableview cell is the following

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"aCell"];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"aCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:165.0/255.0 green:15.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:165.0/255.0 green:15.0/255.0 blue:2.0/255.0 alpha:1];
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Medium" size:22.0f];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0  blue:243.0/255.0  alpha:1];
UIView * separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 2)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"QastItBackground"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;


NSDictionary *categories = [Options categories];
NSArray *details = [categories objectForKey:self.title];
NSString *detail = details [indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = detail;

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *selection = cell.textLabel.text;
[[TemporarySelection sharedStore]updateSelection:selection];
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Two Ways"]) {
    TwoWaysViewController *twvc = [[TwoWaysViewController alloc]init];
    twvc = (TwoWaysViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwoWays"];
    [self presentViewController:twvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());

} else {

DieFacesViewController *dfvc = (DieFacesViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DieFaces"];
[self presentViewController:dfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());

}
}
```

then in the new view controller I take the value from the singleton and I compare it with another string

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

NSString *ts = [[TemporarySelection sharedStore]temporarySelection];

NSArray *favourites = [[FavouritesStore sharedStore]allFavourites];
NSArray *selectedFaces = [[SelectedStore sharedStore]selectedOptions];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectorbg"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

self.selectionName.text = ts;

NSLog(@"%@", ts);
NSLog(@"%@", selectedFaces[0] );


if ([self.selectionName.description isEqualToString: selectedFaces[0]]) {
    self.faceOne.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face1red"];
} else if (selectedFaces[0] == [NSNull null]) {
    self.faceOne.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face1white"];
} else {
    self.faceOne.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face1grey"];
}
}
```

the NSLog show the correct string and with the breakpoint everything is smooth till the first if statement. if I remove it the second statement is fine, so the problem has to lie on the *ts NSString. 
I have another tableview with a custom class cell via interface builder and it has the same problem. I know it can sound very confusing, but I tried everything I can think of and that seem to be the cause.

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: I added the code, but I have the same problem using interface builder.

Comment: did u try self.selectionName.text instead of self.selectionName.description in the first if condition ?

Comment: yes I did, this was one of my desperate attempt to see if anything worked.

Comment: What exactly is self.selectionName? Also, are you sure that selectedFaces[0] returns an NSString?

Comment: Hi guys, problem solved. basically the NSString I was passing could sometimes have been nil. the compiler didn't seem to care until I added the minimum font scale. Being quite new I didn't think passing a null string would make a fuss, I thought it was just going to be ignored, also because that's what it seemed to be happening. Now I just check if selectedFaces[x] is null to start with and everything is sweet. thanks for your help!